# 2dsphere compound index doesn't utilize sort keys

Tags: mongodb

### Problem

The query below isn't using the index for its sorting.

I've trimmed down this query for brevity and it still shows the same behavior. Why does this query have a SORT stage (implying it can't do the sort in the index: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/explain-results/#sort-stage)

### Query

```
db.search.find({
    fooId: 24,
    "location" : {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$centerSphere": [[-88.0582553, 41.5858604], 10 / 3963.2]
        }

    }
})
.limit(300)
.sort({ fooSort: -1, barSort: -1 })
.hint("fooId_1_location_2dsphere_fooSort_-1_barSort_-1")
.explain("executionStats");
```

### Index

```
{
    "fooId" : 1.0,
    "location" : "2dsphere",
    "fooSort" : -1.0,
    "barSort" : -1.0
}
```

### Execution stats (heavily trimmed for brevity):

```
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 300,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 8860,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 54908,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 54885,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "nReturned" : 300,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 8843,
        ...
        "sortPattern" : {
            "fooSort" : -1.0,
            "barSort" : -1.0
        },
        "limitAmount" : 300,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            ...
            "inputStage" : {
                ...
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "indexName" : "fooId_1_location_2dsphere_fooSort_-1_barSort_-1",
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### What I've Tried

Reordering:

- 2dsphere first
- Sort keys first
- 2dsphere last

So far the index above is the most efficient configuration, but still not what I'm looking for. I need the sort to be covered by the index for this query to be efficient, but it seems like no matter what, it's not using the index for the sort. Is this a consequence of using a 2dsphere index?

I'm leveraging this article for advice on the order of keys in an index:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-dynamic-indexer#step-3-compute-the-optimal-index-for-each-query-profile

but it doesn't mention 2dsphere indexes, so I'm wondering if 2dsphere indexes are an exception to this wisdom.

When I remove the sort from the query, it takes about 1/3 as long to run and examines about half as many keys and documents. This is roughly what I'm hoping to achieve with an index and sort.

Mongo 3.4

Comment: No idea if it helps but have you tried creating a second index instead of just one that covers everything? Also, there is this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29647, which, however, is probably just as unrelated. ;)

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, any solutions?